# Firefox Refresh Glitch

Tags: javascript, css, performance, firefox, web-deployment

On the contact portion of my [website](https://www.christopherfrydryck.cf/contact.html), I noticed that there is a visual glitch only with Firefox that causes the JSFiddle SVG (and possibly others as well underneath it) to be a full size at refresh.  Even after cache it does this.  It does not occur on any other browsers. Have any of you seen similar issues to this?

It appears to work well on all other browsers including Chrome, Opera, Edge, etc.  My fix with all other browsers for any flashing at refresh was to create a second class for things called .hiddenOnLoad and gave it a CSS display: none;

However, it appears that Firefox does not want to follow this rule and display my SVG even when it is supposed to be hidden until requested to fade in.

Comment: Can't repro, but it might be that they failed to load your contact.css. Anyway, to avoid this icon to be as large as your screen width, simply add a `width` and `height` attribute on your `<svg>` element, just like you did for all other icons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove at least the `<a>` tag on the `<head>` section:

```
<a name="top"></a>
```

You can also find other unnecessary tags and errors in your markup with the help of the W3C Markup Validation Service, like this: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.christopherfrydryck.cf%2Fcontact.html

Comment: You are welcome. Do not forget to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers